# Mod election process: set up of existing mods and how candidates compare to that

Tags: discussion, election

I seemingly have missed the right timing for the question collection but something I came to think about when reading candidates presentations was "*how do these folks compare to the already existing mods?*"

So I think it would be beneficial to know who are the existing mods, how much time they currently spend moderating (if this is measurable) and of course which time zone they are in.

It's not like we take as much traffic as SO but would still be an idea going forward, in terms of diversity and availability I think.

What do you say? Would it contribute positively for the future elections?

Comment: I am going with the answer to this question is such an obvious yes, that you should just edit this question a little to give us/me a little more guidance about what you want.

Comment: @StrongBad ok, let me rephrase that: "Why do we not have a listing of the current moderator team on the election thread, together with their timezones and subjects of research/academia etc, so that voters can see how candidates relate to/complement/.. the existing mod team?"